# How to evaluate escape character when reading a text file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, readline

I have text file which is like this:

```
["RUN DATE:  2/08/18   9:00:24     USER:XXXXXX        DISPLAY: MENULIST           PROG NAME: MH4567 PAGE 1\nMENU:     ADCS00        Visual Basic Things 
Service\n                                              80 Printer / Message Control\n                                              90 Sign Off\nSelection or 
command\n===>____________________________________________________________________________\n____________________________________________________________________________
____\n F3=Exit      F4=Prompt    F9=Retrieve    F12=Previous\n 80 CALL PGM(GUCMD)\nAUTHORIZED: DOAPROCESS FDOAPROCES FOESUPR     FPROGRAMMR OESUPR     PROGRAMMER\n 
90 SIGNOFF\nAUTHORIZED: DOAPROCESS FDOAPROCES FOESUPR     FPROGRAMMR OESUPR     PROGRAMMER\n", "RUN DATE:   5/09/19    9:00:24     USER:XXXXXX        DISPLAY: 
MENULIST                                PROG NAME: MH4567    PAGE 2\nMENU:      APM001         Accounts Payable Menu\n      MENU 
OPTIONS                                 DISPLAY PROGRAMS\n  1   Radar Processing                         30 Vendor\n  2   Prepaid Processing                        
31 Prepaid\n"]
```

`I want to translate every '\n' as new line and then print.`

I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
 import json
 contents = open("file.txt", "r")
 Lines = contents.readlines() 
 for l in Lines:
    print(l)
```

The above code prints end of line in .txt file as new line without observing the actual '\n' character?

Comment: If that is what you have `\n` *is* a new line.  Lists print string using "programmer-friendly" string that shows unprintable characters as escape codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
with open('./sample.txt', 'r') as file_:
    txt = file_.read().replace('\\n', '\n')
    print(txt)
```

**Output**

```
"RUN DATE:  2/08/18   9:00:24     USER:XXXXXX        DISPLAY: MENULIST           PROG NAME: MH4567 PAGE 1
MENU:     ADCS00        Visual Basic Things 
Service
                                              80 Printer / Message Control
                                              90 Sign Off
Selection or 
command
===>____________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________
____
 F3=Exit      F4=Prompt    F9=Retrieve    F12=Previous
 80 CALL PGM(GUCMD)
AUTHORIZED: DOAPROCESS FDOAPROCES FOESUPR     FPROGRAMMR OESUPR     PROGRAMMER
 
90 SIGNOFF
AUTHORIZED: DOAPROCESS FDOAPROCES FOESUPR     FPROGRAMMR OESUPR     PROGRAMMER
", "RUN DATE:   5/09/19    9:00:24     USER:XXXXXX        DISPLAY: 
MENULIST                                PROG NAME: MH4567    PAGE 2
MENU:      APM001         Accounts Payable Menu
      MENU 
OPTIONS                                 DISPLAY PROGRAMS
  1   Radar Processing                         30 Vendor
  2   Prepaid Processing                        
31 Prepaid
"
```